# How to sort aggregated numpy array?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, aggregate

My first post on stackoverflow + am very new to programming. Apologies in advance for any poor formatting and missing information. :)

I aggregated two columns in a csv file (one column of seller names, the other of transactional amounts) to find how much each seller has made in total:

```
seller_group = df.groupby(["seller"])
#Total amount each seller has made so far
seller_group.aggregate({'price_paid':np.sum})
```

I want to sort it in descending order to find who the top sellers are, so I tried this:

```
to_sort = seller_group.aggregate({'price_paid':np.sum})
to_sort(x)[::-1]
```

The result is a numpy series without the seller column and the prices are formatted strangely (for example, [5.00000e+00]). I'd like a result that looks like this, but with the price_paid column sorted: [seller sums output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpcPx.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: `seller_group.aggregate({'price_paid':np.sum}).sort_values(by="price_paid")` ?

Comment: This is very close! However, the result is in ascending order instead of descending.

Comment: Pass `ascending=False` to `sort_values`.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values):

```py
df_out = seller_group.aggregate({'price_paid':np.sum}).sort_values(by="price_paid", ascending=False)
```